# Pass parameters to SQL Server insert query from multiple different events

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters

I am writing a Winforms app in Visual Studio 2013 that has several forms. I am adding an event log to see who is using what, login times, logoff times, etc. (all harmless, this is a management tool for team at work). I want to simplify and reduce the length of code needed.

Right now I have the below code in each Event Sub on all forms.

```
 Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server= server\instance; Database = db;
                                      User ID=uID;Password=pw")

 Private Sub btnAssociate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAssociate.Click
    Dim eLogCMD As New SqlCommand("sp_EventLog", connection)
    Me.connection.Open()
    eLogCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    eLogCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login.UsernameTextBox.Text.ToString())
    eLogCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "AssociateArea")
    eLogCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", "Entered Associate Area")
    eLogCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Me.connection.Close()
```

There are several other Subs, all with same code, and multiple forms with same connection, `SqlCommand`, and parameters declared; only the parameter values change. It works, but there has got to be a cleaner way.

I want to create one `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` on the main form to call and pass parameters to from different forms and event subs. I'm looking for something easy like this:

```
Sub --Whatever Event
    Main.eLogCMD.ExecuteNonQuery(1stParameterValue, 2ndParameterValue, 3rdParameterValue)
End Sub
```

Showing the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_EventLog]        
     @Username VARCHAR(50),
     @Action   VARCHAR(30),
     @Comments VARCHAR(100)     
AS       
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AppEventLog ([Username], [Action], [Comments])
    VALUES (@Username, @Action, @Comments)      
END
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot move that logic to a shared module?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @soohoonigan I have not found anything that would help, I apologize, I am relatively new to VB

Comment: @marc_s Thanks, I will change that.

Comment: No problem, was just curious if you had already considered it and decided it wouldn't work for some reason. In any case, Joel has written a great example and that is the right way to handle your problem. If you're still new to VB, don't hesitate to ask for clarification on his answer if there's part of it you don't understand. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make this part of any form. Instead, you can put the code in it's own Module. Then call a method on the Module with just the arguments you need to write the log.

Don't try to re-use the same connection *object* across your application. That will interfere with a feature in ADO.Net called Connection Pooling. You can (and should) re-use the same connection string, but that's different.

```vb
Public Module Events 
    Private CnString As String = "Server= server\instance; Database = db; User ID=uID;Password=pw"

    Public Sub LogAction(User As String, ActionName As String, Comment As String)
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(CnString), _
              LogCmd As New SqlCommand("sp_EventLog", cn)

            LogCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            'AVOID ADDWITHVALUE()! It can cause significant performance problems
            'Instead, set these to match actual column types and lengths from the DB
            LogCmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = User
            LogCmd.Parameters.Add("@Action", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 80).Value = ActionName
            LogCmd.Parameters.Add("@Comments", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500).Value = Comment

            cn.Open()
            LogCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub  
End Module
```

Then your existing methods reduce to using this pattern:

```vb
Private Sub btnAssociate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAssociate.Click
    Events.LogAction(Login.UsernameTextBox.Text, "AssociateArea", "Entered Associate Area")

    '...
End Sub
```

Ideally, **ALL** database access will run through a Module like this, where user interface events never directly talk to the database and instead only call methods on your DataBase module.

Comment: OP, this is your answer.  Please accept it!  Joel, +1.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. This is exactly what I was looking for